# After installing a mobile AC, I do have hot air intake from the front door

Tags: hvac

I have installed an appliance like the following one:

[image]

Its hose is connected to what acts as the 'chimney' of the building.

Now whenever I turn it on, I can feel that hot air is coming from the front door.

**Question:**

Is my setup wrong or is this to be expected with a mobile AC but can be mitigated somehow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those mobile A/Cs draw air from inside the room, cool it, and return most of it back into the room. Some air is used to cool the unit and is exhausted, in your case up your 'chimney'. This causes a small negative pressure, which will draw air from adjacent, unsealed areas (in your case, your front door).

There are dual-hose mobile A/Cs that use external air to cool the compressor, but that doesn't really help solve your current problem.

I would say that it's just to be expected; the price to pay for a cheap, mobile A/C.

Comment: Alright, we're not allowed to install real AC in the building, life would have been much easier (cooler) actually !

Comment: Some "historic" apartment buildings in the US also prohibit residents from installing a/c window units or even minisplit units. The minisplit condensing units could be somewhat hidden on a balcony, but if they are hung on the exterior wall, it does detract from the appearance. As the world heats up I would expect a relaxation of these rules, but that doesn't help you now..

Comment: In fact, most if not all buildings should be rebuilt but this will definitely not happen any time soon! Wish me good luck, today we'll have 43c, previous record was in 1947 :)

Comment: If this is a long-term solution, try to get a dual-hose model.  They are much more efficient.  These single hose units are really only good for temporary or emergency use.

Comment: Definitely going to look into that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An air conditioner has two airflows (for a total of 4 ducts: 2 in and 2 out.

- Working room air, where it takes air from the room, **cools it off**, and returns it to the room. This is the service you are paying for.
- Heat-sink air air, where it takes air from ???, **warms it up**, and ejects it outside (certainly NOT in the room!)

The "???" has two choices.

One of them is to intake air from *inside the room*.  The upside is this only requires one pipe.  The downside is that all the air it ejects reduces the pressure in the room, causing the equal amount of additional air to leak *into the room* from outside.  This air is both warm and moist, exactly what you are trying to avoid, and yes - this warms up the room and partially defeats the purpose of the air conditioner.

The other approach is to intake air from outside using a second hose.  In this case, the heat-sink loop intakes from outside and exhausts to outside, so it does not depressurize the room. If those two vents are too close together, there's a risk of it ingesting its own output air, which will be warmer of course, and that will hurt efficiency.  But by and large, a 2-pipe system is vastly superior and will eliminate those hot drafts.  Of course, that is not competitive; most people want the convenience of a single pipe.

Comment: Do you have any idea on why does the region back of the AC gets much hotter than even initial room temperature ? I can't believe this comes from the hose, rather external heat that piles up but I'm not sure in the end.

Comment: @Aybe Learn more about vapor-compression refrigeration works and you'll understand why the output pipe is so hot.  Hint: cold is lack of heat, and heat can't be destroyed, so it has to go *somewhere*...

Comment: I will, thanks for the heads up!